# cycle through variables and assign all numers

Tags: python

So I want to cycle through variables A through J and assign numbers 0 through 9
but in a way that it goes through all possible combinations (yeah it's a lot)
the code that I came  up with is as follows

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0
h = 0
i = 0
j = 0

checkedValues = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
firstCycle = True

values = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
running  = True
i = 0
j = 0
while running == True:
    if not checkedValues[i]:
        for temp in range(10):
            j = temp + i
            if j < 10:
                values[temp] = j
            else:
                j -= 10
                values[temp] = j

    i += 1
    print(values)
    if i == 9:
        i = 0
        tempvar = values.pop(0)
        values.append(tempvar)

    if values == [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]:
        if firstCycle:
            firstCycle = False
        else:
            break
```

Question is if there are ways to do this faster and more efficiently.

edit: this code, kinda, works. Besides optimization problems, I also run into the issue that I want the variables to be seen separately from the list/array that they're in. Only putting them in the list/array in the first place so that I can easily cycle through them to change the variables

Comment: Why did you make all of those separate variables instead of them being a list in the first place?

Comment: builtin `itertools`?

Comment: Also the `checkedValues` list seems completely redundant since you never modify it

Comment: Can you show us the desired output/result. I don't understand what you mean with "all possible combinations".

Comment: 1. I think to use variables in a list you need to declare them first, and you can't just declare variables in the list? I'm planning to do some calculations afterwards so needing them to be variables?

Comment: 2. thanks, will look at it

Comment: 3. yeah it does appear that way, just something that I first used to double checked and then later worked around, thanks for posting it

Comment: 4. I'm not that good at explaining what I want so a bit tough, but want to generate every single combination of numbers between 0 and 9 in 9 slots. With a smaller sample size it would be 0/1/2
0/2/1
1/0/2
1/0/1
1/2/0
2/1/0
2/0/1
but with 9 digits

Comment: "I think to use variables in a list you need to declare them first"  - No, your only variable should be the list.

Comment: doing that gives me an "unresolved reference" error for all of the variables tho

Comment: Where else do you use the `a` to `j` variables? In the posted code they are redundant, as the `values` creation can be replaced by a regular list (of `0`) and the `if values ==` can be replaced with `if not any(values):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you provide some context to your question. But anyways I hope I got what you want to achieve - here would be my suggestion:

```
import itertools

min = 0
max = 9
possible_choices = [i for i in range(min, max + 1)]
all_combinations = list(itertools.permutations(possible_choices))
print(all_combinations)

for combination in all_combinations:
    # cycle through the results and do whatever you need to do
    print(combination)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick and runs a lot smoother then what I had kinda had worked out

Comment: Please explain your solution. Code only is not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Luckily for your PC, I have completely misunderstood the question at first, the problem can be solved as following:

```
max_val = 10
values = list(range(max_val))
result = [[(i + j) % max_val for i in values] for j in values]
```

I have used a double list comprehension to make it shorter. The code is somewhat equivalent to:

```
results = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
    for j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
        results[i, j] = (i + j) % 10
```

Just for reference, I have previously assumed that you want to have a series of 10-long lists of all combinations of numbers from 0 to 10, which should be something like 10'000'000'000 elements long, hence my worry and use of `itertools.product`.

---

Edit: It looks like you indeed want to get all combinations, in which case the answer by Tetrick25 looks reasonable.

Comment: Please explain your solution and the sub-results between the steps.

Comment: The point of using `product` is that you can have it generate elements as you iterate over it. Wrapping it in `list` tries to realize all the values at once.

Comment: taking the example of max_val = 3 gives me: 0/1/2, 1/2/0, 2/0/1. While the full list should be: 0/1/2, 0/2/1, 1/0/2, 1/0/1, 1/2/0, 2/1/0, 2/0/1

Comment: Well, your output suggests that it should be only 0/1/2, 1/2/0, 2/0/1. My initial answer aimed to give all combinations, but you specified your requirements so that I have changed it...